# Regarding WorkFlow Rule

Tags: workflow

I have created a New Workflow Rule,with the formula Evalutes true

```
AND(
  $User.ProfileId='00e280000013sw7',
  JDE_Ship_Sold_To_Account__c <> NULL,
  ISPICKVAL(Type__c,'X')
)  
AND(
  $User.ProfileId='00e280000013sw7',
  JDE_Ship_Sold_To_Account__c <> NULL,
  ISPICKVAL(Type__c,'XC')
)
AND(
  $User.ProfileId='00e280000013sw7',
  JDE_Ship_Sold_To_Account__c <> NULL,
  ISPICKVAL(Type__c,'XCS')
)
```

**Above formula if one Conditon is true it will execute the Field Update,How to write Formula for above field**,**i want formula to write for any one of the Condition to be true**

it is Showing Syntax error. Extra AND
Check Syntax  Please How to Retify the error

Comment: Since you've rejected all the provided answers so far, It would be helpful if you could give us a better explanation of exactly what it is that you're looking for by making an **[edit](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/138465/edit)** to your question. We can't see what your Salesforce org looks like. Be as detailed as possible. Assume that we know nothing about your situation other than that you're using Salesforce and are writing a Workflow rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula should work for you

```
AND
(
    $User.ProfileId='00e280000013sw7',
    JDE_Ship_Sold_To_Account__c <> NULL,
    OR
    (
        ISPICKVAL(Type__c,'X'),
        ISPICKVAL(Type__c,'XC'),
        ISPICKVAL(Type__c,'XCS')
    )
)
```

Since the ProfileID and Custom Field were the same in all conditions I combined them.

This will check that the User's Profile is  the specified ID, and `JDE_Ship_SOld_To_Account__c` is not NULL and `Type__c` is either `X`, `XC`, or `XCS`

Answer (score 3):

After editing your question to make the workflow rule criteria more readable, it becomes quite easy to see what's wrong.

The main issue is those 3 `AND(...)` statements that you have back to back. There's nothing to connect them. That's where you're running into the syntax error.

Now, you could fix that issue by wrapping your entire formula inside an `OR()`, but this brings us to the secondary issue.

The first two conditions in each of your `AND(...)`s are exactly the same. There's no reason to repeat it over and over. You can simplify your logic like this

```
AND(
   <first condition>,
   <second condition>,
   OR(
     <check your picklist field for the 3 values you're interested in>
   )
)
```

Comment: @user36188 Saying that it isn't working with no explanation doesn't help. What exactly about it isn't working? It might also help to **[edit](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/138465/edit)** your question to include the updated formula that you're trying to use (and don't delete the original formula you were using from your question).